# Testing rendered content of a .gsp page in Grails 2.3.8

Tags: grails, testing

First time asking here. I'll cut right to the chase. I'm trying to test the rendered view of a controller, and I haven't found any clear way to do it. In particular, what I'm trying to do is test the actual content of the .gsp rendered; namely, if the html page rendered contains a list of items (list, as in a `<ul>` and `<li>` tags, for example), or any other content the page should display. Is this possible? Or even a valid approach to test this kind of thing? I tried doing something like this:

The controller:

```
class ConnectedPairController {

    def show(int id) {
        //Some logic to populate collections and stuff

        render(view:"show.gsp", model:['pqc':cp.getPath(),
                           'connected':cp.getPage(), 
                           'instance':coll, 
                           'pagesCollection':colPages])
    }
```

The test:

```
@TestFor(ConnectedPairController)

    class ConnectedPairControllerSpec extends Specification {
        void "test show"() {    
        when:
            controller.show(4) //4 being the id of the content I want to display
        then:
            controller.response.text.contains "Some string or html tag the page should display"
        }
    }
```

But the text returned is null. Maybe this is how it should be, but is there a way to get the rendered content?

What I found in the documentation is not useful (at least not for what I want to do), since IMHO it only tests trivial stuff, like what .gsp is being rendered, or the content of variables:

```
@TestFor(SimpleController)
class SimpleControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void 'test home'() {
    when:
    controller.home()

    then:
    view == '/simple/homePage'
    model.title == 'Hello World'
    }
}
```

I hope I'm being clear enough. Thank you for your time.

PS: I'm using Grails 2.3.8. If you need any other information related to the environment and such, please let me know.

Comment: If I get more time later today, I'll turn this link into an answer. In the mean time, try this method: http://www.grailstraining.com/groovy/testing-your-gsp-views-from-integration-tests

Answer (score 0):

The response is not fully rendered in a unit test.  [response.text will always be null when rendering views.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122666/grails-controller-unit-test-doesnt-render-page-to-response-text)

The purpose of a unit test is to test one unit and mock out everything around it.  The view layer is outside that unit.

If you want to test the view, try the [GroovyPageUnitTestMixin](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.8/api/grails/test/mixin/web/GroovyPageUnitTestMixin.html)

Mr. Haki has a [good post on how to test views and templates](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/05/grails-goodness-testing-views-and.html) that explains how to test them.

Answer (score 0):

@ColinHarrington Thanks for your answer, and sorry for the delay. I have tried what it says on those websites, but no matter what view (.gsp) I render (like a simple page that just renders the content of a variable), the `render` method always returns `null` (not even an empty string).

The controller:

```
class TestingController {

    def index() {
        render view: "testing.gsp", model: [test:"Test String"]
    }
}
```

The test:

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.web.GroovyPageUnitTestMixin
import spock.lang.Specification


@TestMixin(GroovyPageUnitTestMixin)
class TestingControllerSpec extends Specification {
    def controller

    def setup() {
        controller = testFor(TestingController)
    }

    void "test something"() {
        when:
            controller.index()
        then:
            render (view:"/testing/testing.gsp", model:model) == "Test String"
    }
}
```

Test result:

```
test something(webbluefinder.TestingControllerSpec)
 |
Condition not satisfied:
render (view:"/testing/testing.gsp", model:model) == "Test String"
|                                          |      |
null                                       |      false
                                       [test:Test String]
```

I also tried Mr. Haki's approach, and got the same result.
Do you happen to know why this is happening? Thanks for your time.